# how to fix Flutter page with textfield not working

Tags: flutter

I started Flutter but on this page have some unknown issues.
This issue is happening when i add textform here.
I am not sure what is wrong here.
Please anybody help me.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RequestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String routeName = "/request";
  RequestPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _RequestPageState createState() => _RequestPageState();
}

class _RequestPageState extends State<RequestPage> {

  Widget _textForm(){
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: TextField(
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Password',
              ),
            )
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              "assets/img/RequestPage/background.png",
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
            _textForm(),
          ]);
  }
}
```

Well, i built another page like this but that page is working correctly.
So i think the main issue on this page is not layout problem or package problem.
Thanks

Comment: what kind of error are you facing?

Comment: Hi @AR i am not sure about what kind of error, just showing too much lines like ```I/flutter (21889): #36     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5452:14)
I/flutter (21889): #37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
(package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4413:5)```